# Alternate turn during button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

If I click a button it should take alternative `X` and `O`. but it is taking only `X` but not `O` why?

I have taken turn as a Boolean variable and used reverse symbol for taking alternatives.

```
Button b = (Button)sender;
if (turn)
{
    b.Text = "X";
}
else
{ 
    b.Text = "O";
}
turn = !turn;
```

Comment: Where is `turn` being declared? You need to provide complete code for your question.

Comment: I declared turn at first as a Boolean variable

Comment: Unless `turn` is persisted in Session or something else, it will reset because web pages are stateless.

Comment: Yes, but if it is scoped locally to the procedure, it will always initialize each run.

Comment: You want me to declare turn before if loop.

Comment: Like I said, you need to provide compete code. If your `if` statement is declared in a button click, and your `turn` variable is declared in the same routine, it will reinitialize each run. The `turn` variable needs to be declared globally in the class. Also, keep in mind what @Crowcoder said, that variable, unless in a session, is going to lose its value and be reinitialize each time the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something a long these lines:

```
protected void btnExample_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    if(Session["Turn"] == null)
         Session.Add("Turn", true);

    var turn = (bool)Session["Turn"];
    if(turn)
    {
         Session["Turn"] = false;
         button.Text = "X";
    }

    else
    {
        Session["Turn"] = true;
        button.Text = "O";
    }
}
```

You're using a global in essence with the session, which can introduce problems and odd test cases.  Especially since it expires over a short duration, but this would work.  With more requirements a better answer may ensue, however you get the notion of the code and why it tracks over a larger period of time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on why you're using a variable here -- it looks like you're just toggling the button text between two values...  If so, why not:

```
Button b = (Button)sender;
if (b.Text = "0")
{
    b.Text = "X";
}
else
{ 
    b.Text = "O";
}
```

Or if you must use a 'turn' variable, then you need to initialize it based on whatever the determining factor may be -- ex:

```
if (b.Text = "X") /*or whatever the determining factor is -- maybe you need to do a lookup here instead -- request.querysting("turn"), viewstate("turn"), etc.*/
{
    turn = 1;
}
else
{ 
    turn = 0;
}
```

then you can change the button text:

```
Button b = (Button)sender;
if (turn)
{
    b.Text = "X";
}
else
{ 
    b.Text = "O";
}
```

And then here -- if you're storing the new value of 'turn' somewhere...

```
viewstate("turn") = !turn;
```

(or wherever you're storing it...)